# Change icon for a panel item

Tags: icons, panel, ubuntu-mate

I added a Force Quit button to my panel.

But when I try to change it's icon by right clicking it, there is no Properties pick that I would need.

Any workaround? Ubuntu Mate 18.04
Thanks.

I did a search and found force-quit.png and force-quit.svg.

Assuming I can find the right icon, can I substitute my custom icon and
name it force-quit.png?

Comment: You can try that, followed by `mate-panel --replace &` to restart panel.

Comment: Good chance that's the icon or icons.  You can experiment by renaming them to backup copies and then copying your own icon or icons using the original names.  If it doesn't work then just put the original icons back.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, my answer incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It took quite a lot of searching.

The icon is secretly located here.

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/mate-panel-force-quit.png
```

I renamed it mate-panel-force-quit1.png(Just in case.) and then placed my custom icon in that directory.